# Byte Array and Int conversion in Java

Tags: java

I am having some difficulty with these two functions: `byteArrayToInt` and `intToByteArray`.

The problem is that if I use one to get to another and that result to get to the former, the results are different, as you can see from my examples below.

I cannot find the bug in the code. Any ideas are very welcome. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a = 123;
    byte[] aBytes = intToByteArray(a);
    int a2 = byteArrayToInt(aBytes);

    System.out.println(a);         // prints '123'
    System.out.println(aBytes);    // prints '[B@459189e1'
    System.out.println(a2);        // prints '2063597568
            System.out.println(intToByteArray(a2));  // prints '[B@459189e1'
}

public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) 
{
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int shift = (4 - 1 - i) * 8;
        value += (b[i] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
    }
    return value;
}

public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[4];
    ret[0] = (byte) (a & 0xFF);   
    ret[1] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);   
    ret[2] = (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF);   
    ret[3] = (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the loop in `byteArrayToInt`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're swapping [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) between your two methods.  You have `intToByteArray(int a)` assigning the low-order bits into `ret[0]`, but then `byteArrayToInt(byte[] b)` assigns `b[0]` to the high-order bits of the result.  You need to invert one or the other, like:

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[4];
    ret[3] = (byte) (a & 0xFF);   
    ret[2] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);   
    ret[1] = (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF);   
    ret[0] = (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `ByteBuffer class`, I've created an example around it.

Answer (score 60):

Your methods should be (something like)

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) 
{
    return   b[3] & 0xFF |
            (b[2] & 0xFF) << 8 |
            (b[1] & 0xFF) << 16 |
            (b[0] & 0xFF) << 24;
}

public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
    return new byte[] {
        (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF),
        (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF),   
        (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF),   
        (byte) (a & 0xFF)
    };
}
```

These methods were tested with the following code :

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
byte[] b;
int a, v;
for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
    a = rand.nextInt();
    b = intToByteArray(a);
    v = byteArrayToInt(b);
    if (a != v) {
        System.out.println("ERR! " + a + " != " + Arrays.toString(b) + " != " + v);
    }
}
System.out.println("Done!");
```

Comment: @owlstead, yes, your code would work best to convert a `byte[]` into `int[]`, however for isolated conversion of `byte` to `int`, using direct bit manipulation (especially when you *know* and *expect* the defined data to be properly formed) is a *way* lot faster than creating an instance of a class to do the exact same thing for each call. Even if you cache an instance of `ByteBuffer`, you'd still have to copy the passing bytes to the buffer's array, thus gives you some overhead in any case.

Comment: @owlstead, perhaps, but if you can optimize a method from the start, and it is a really simple one, why would you settle for less? You don't need a reusable pattern here.. and, besides, the accumulation of "small price to pay" can escalate quite fast in a big project. Think about it.

Comment: yes, this answer is a tidy old. I don't know why I used a `for` block for the first method...

Comment: updated methods to remove unnecessary loops and intermediary variables

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the `intToByteArray` method, why do you have to AND `0xFF` to each byte before converting it back to a byte? 0xFF would include all 8 bits. And a byte is only 8 bits. So the code ` & 0xFF` seems pointless.

Comment: @WaffleStealer654: That's needed because Java bytes are signed, so if the top bit is on it's a negative number with one bits in all the high-order bits when converted to an int. (The fact that Java bytes are signed is, well, to be polite, non-optimal in my opinion, but that's the way they are.)

Comment: I'd say -  man, who made them signed hardly live a minute when bump into cross-platform programmers on a night street. The biggest mistake in the whole languge.

Comment: @Kayla Have to agree because we need to worry about sign-extension only in case of widening conversions.

Comment: Cool..........................

Answer (score 50):

That's a lot of work for:

```
public static int byteArrayToLeInt(byte[] b) {
    final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return bb.getInt();
}

public static byte[] leIntToByteArray(int i) {
    final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bb.putInt(i);
    return bb.array();
}
```

This method uses the Java [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [`ByteOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html) functionality in the [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) package. This code should be preferred where readability is required. It should also be very easy to remember.

I've shown Little Endian byte order here. To create a Big Endian version you can simply leave out the call to [`order(ByteOrder)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-).

---

In code where performance is higher priority than readability (about 10x as fast):

```
public static int byteArrayToLeInt(byte[] encodedValue) {
    int value = (encodedValue[3] << (Byte.SIZE * 3));
    value |= (encodedValue[2] & 0xFF) << (Byte.SIZE * 2);
    value |= (encodedValue[1] & 0xFF) << (Byte.SIZE * 1);
    value |= (encodedValue[0] & 0xFF);
    return value;
}

public static byte[] leIntToByteArray(int value) {
    byte[] encodedValue = new byte[Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE];
    encodedValue[3] = (byte) (value >> Byte.SIZE * 3);
    encodedValue[2] = (byte) (value >> Byte.SIZE * 2);   
    encodedValue[1] = (byte) (value >> Byte.SIZE);   
    encodedValue[0] = (byte) value;
    return encodedValue;
}
```

Just reverse the byte array index to count from zero to three to create a Big Endian version of this code.

---

Notes:

- In Java 8 you can also make use of the [`Integer.BYTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#BYTES) constant, which is more succinct than `Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE`.

Comment: One liner: `byte[] result = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(i).array();`

Comment: OK, so there was an interesting discussion with Yanick about performance, so I've added a performance enhanced version, using Yanick's answer (upvoted) as base. The most important change is the removal of the `for` loop of course, as branching is slow on current CPU's. It's therefore at least twice as fast.

Comment: Isn't there an inconsistency between your short version and your performance version? The sort version is for little-endian and the performance version is for big-endian?

Comment: @RenniePet Ah, yeah, should have made that more clear. I'll add a LE version of the performance version later.

Comment: From the performance version of `byteArrayToLeInt`, why didn't you AND the `encodedValue[3]` by `0xff`?

Comment: @mr5 The 0xFF is to remove the topmost bits from the converted byte. If the byte has a MSB bit set to 1 then sign extension will translate the resulting int in a negative value as well. So all the higher bits of the integer are set to 1. However, if you shift these 24 (**3** times 8) bits into the bit bucket right after that then that doesn't matter much.

Comment: +1 for a solution, allowing to change the endianess. This helped me correctly converting a piece of C code to readable Java.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use BigInteger for variable length bytes. You can convert it to Long, Integer or Short, whichever suits your needs.

```
new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
```

or to denote polarity:

```
new BigInteger(1, bytes).intValue();
```

To get bytes back just:

```
new BigInteger(bytes).toByteArray()
```

Comment: Great, simple, flexible answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Duffmaster33 Simple, but slow... and too much garbage collection pressure. But +1 anyway :)

Comment: @St.Antario Thanks for the comment, would you mind elaborating?  I'm curious

Comment: @Duffmaster33 This can be seen if we run simple `JMH`-benchmark. I ran it with `-prof gc` and saw that with default parameters on a single fork 5 warmup and 5 iterations I got 16 Minor GC with allocation rate `500 MB/sec`. On my machine it's about 10 times slower.

Comment: @Duffmaster33 I just decompiled the version with bitwise operations and noticed that all these `movsbl  0x13(%r11),%r10d movsbl  0x11(%r11),%eax movsbl  0x12(%r11),%r8d movzbl  0x10(%r11),%r9d` And these all `or`-ed.

Answer (score 2):

I like owlstead's original answer, and if you don't like the idea of creating a `ByteBuffer` on every method call then you can reuse the `ByteBuffer` by calling it's `.clear()` and `.flip()` methods:

```
ByteBuffer _intShifter = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE)
                                   .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

public byte[] intToByte(int value) {
    _intShifter.clear();
    _intShifter.putInt(value);      
    return _intShifter.array();
}

public int byteToInt(byte[] data)
{
    _intShifter.clear();
    _intShifter.put(data, 0, Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE);
    _intShifter.flip();
    return _intShifter.getInt();
}
```

Comment: Yup, just don't re-use the buffer in multi-threaded code, that would get you in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple way in com.google.common.primitives which is in the [Maven:com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1]

```
long newLong = Longs.fromByteArray(oldLongByteArray);
int newInt = Ints.fromByteArray(oldIntByteArray);
```

Have a nice try :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a long look at many questions like this, and found [this post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/216874/primitive-types-as-byte-arrays)... I didn't like the fact that the conversion code is duplicated for each type, so I've made a generic method to perform the task:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(long value, int n)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[n];
    ret[n-1] = (byte) ((value >> (0*8) & 0xFF);   
    ret[n-2] = (byte) ((value >> (1*8) & 0xFF);   
    ...
    ret[1] = (byte) ((value >> ((n-2)*8) & 0xFF);   
    ret[0] = (byte) ((value >> ((n-1)*8) & 0xFF);   
    return ret;
}
```

See [full post](http://nu-art-software-development-tips.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/conversion-of-numeric-primitives-to.html).

Comment: Obviously it loops... not hand made :)

Answer (score 0):

/*sorry this is the correct */

```
     public byte[] IntArrayToByteArray(int[] iarray , int sizeofintarray)
     {
       final ByteBuffer bb ;
       bb = ByteBuffer.allocate( sizeofintarray * 4);
       for(int k = 0; k < sizeofintarray ; k++)
       bb.putInt(k * 4, iar[k]);
       return bb.array();
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. An explanation would improve this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of allocating space, et al, an approach using `ByteBuffer` from `java.nio`....

```
byte[] arr = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x01};

// say we want to consider indices 1, 2, 3, 4 {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48};
ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr, 1, 4); // big endian by default
int num = bf.getInt();    // 72
```

Now, to go the other way.

```
ByteBuffer newBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
newBuf.putInt(num);
byte[] bytes = newBuf.array();  // [0, 0, 0, 72] {0x48 = 72}
```

Answer (score -2):

here is my implementation

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(a).toByteArray();
}

public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    return new BigInteger(b).intValue();
}
```

Comment: -1, this will return a different result than asked (it returns the minimum number of bytes instead of 4 bytes). Furthermore, using BigInteger is a bit heavy for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Not as bad as I expected though, only 20x slower than an optimized version :), mine was not that much faster I must admit.