# Java - Convert int to Byte Array of 4 Bytes?

Tags: java, byte, buffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert integer into byte array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java)

I need to store the length of a buffer, in a byte array 4 bytes large.

Pseudo code:

```
private byte[] convertLengthToByte(byte[] myBuffer)
{
    int length = myBuffer.length;

    byte[] byteLength = new byte[4];

    //here is where I need to convert the int length to a byte array
    byteLength = length.toByteArray;

    return byteLength;
}
```

What would be the best way of accomplishing this? Keeping in mind I must convert that byte array back to an integer later.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can convert `yourInt` to bytes by using a `ByteBuffer` like this:

```
return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(yourInt).array();
```

Beware that you might have to think about the [byte order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) when doing so.

Comment: This is better (gets the platform ByteOrder): `ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).putInt(yourInt).array();`

Comment: If it's better depends on what you want to do with it. It may be a little bit faster, but having the byte order depend on the platform is a no-no when you want to send those bytes over a network or even write to a file.

Answer (score 50):

```
public static  byte[] my_int_to_bb_le(int myInteger){
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(myInteger).array();
}

public static int my_bb_to_int_le(byte [] byteBarray){
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(byteBarray).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
}

public static  byte[] my_int_to_bb_be(int myInteger){
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putInt(myInteger).array();
}

public static int my_bb_to_int_be(byte [] byteBarray){
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(byteBarray).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
}
```

Answer (score 24):

This should work:

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value};
}
```

Code [taken from here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/93).

**Edit** An even simpler solution is [given in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array).

Comment: you should be aware of order. in that case order is big endian. from the most significant to the least.

Answer (score 22):

```
int integer = 60;
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)(integer >>> (i * 8));
}
```