# How to convert integers from 0 to 2000 to a byte array of length 2 and vice versa? Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

Well the questions is pretty much as the title. In my application I am sending array with 2 bytes using UDP packets. I want to know if there is a way to convert the integers from 0 to 2000 into bytes array of size two and after that to convert that byte array back to integer?

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374915/java-convert-int-to-byte-array-of-4-bytes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array

Comment: Look here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array

Comment: well these solutions are mainly for 4 bits integer ... my problem is actually how to represent the integers from 0 to 127 as 2 bytes ?

Comment: Do the same thing with a short?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort(short)

Comment: a short is two bytes, use those

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.nio ByteBuffer conversions

to bytes

```
int[] ia = { 1, 2, 3 };
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(ia.length * 4);
for (int i : ia) {
    bb.putShort((short)i);
}
byte[] ba = bb.array();
```

to ints

```
ShortBuffer sb = ByteBuffer.wrap(ba).asShortBuffer();
int[] ia = new int[sb.limit() / 2];
for(int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = sb.get();
}
```