# Store int 0-65535 on fixed 16-bit & convert back

Tags: java

I have `int` numbers with values between 0-65535. I need to store each number as a `byte` array of 2 bytes length, whether the number could fit on 1 byte as well or not. Once the numbers are stored in byte arrays, I need to be able to convert them back to `int`. Right now I don't know how to store a number that is not between -32,768 and 32,767 on 2 bytes and be able to properly convert it back to its original `int` value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Convert int to Byte Array of 4 Bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374915/java-convert-int-to-byte-array-of-4-bytes)

Comment: I need 2 bytes, not 4.

Comment: Look at using shift to access desired byte and AND to stripe off sign bits

Answer (score 1):

You can store values from `0-65535` in a `char`-value and convert a `char` to `byte[]` (with a length of 2) using the following method:

```java
    public static byte[] toBytes(char c) {
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(Character.BYTES).putChar(c).array();
    }
```

See [here](https://gitlab.codeflush.dev/codeflush-public/commons-java/blob/master/src/main/java/dev/codeflush/commons/Primitives.java)

EDIT:

Works backwards using `ByteBuffer` to:

```java
    public static char charFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getChar();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the first byte as: `(byte) (myIntNumber >> 8)` and the second as `(byte) myIntNumber` seems working just fine for int -> byte array conversion, I'm still curious about how do I get back the int properly from a byte array.

Comment: You can just use my solution and cast from `int` to `char` and vice-versa