# How to reverse this code to decode the message from the top line

Tags: java, ascii, bmp

I need to decode a message from the top line of pixels in a BMP picture. There is a message hidden in the red value in binary. I have tried finding a way to do this and haven't succeeded because most programs use .jpg or .png file types for images and BMP images don't work in that code. I need to find out how to reverse this code to decode the message using arrays, and I need to print the message in ASCII text. For some programs, they allowed to me array the top line of the image but I don't know how to print it. Here is the code for encoding the message in the image:

```
import java.awt.*;
class Encode
{
    public void encodeMessage(Picture image, int [] binaryArray)
    {
        Pixel pixelTarget = new Pixel(image,0,0);
        Pixel [] pixelArray = image.getPixels();
        Color pixelColor = null;
        int redValue = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < binaryArray.length; x++)
        {
            redValue = binaryArray[x];
            pixelTarget = pixelArray[x];
            pixelTarget.setRed(redValue);
        }
        pixelTarget = pixelArray[binaryArray.length];
        pixelTarget.setRed(255);

        image.write("SecretMessage.bmp");
        image.explore();
    }
}
public class EncodeTester
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] bitArray = {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1};    
        Picture image = new Picture("earth.bmp");
        Encode message = new Encode();

        message.encodeMessage(image, bitArray);

    }
}
```

Could someone please explain how to continue or write up a sample code for me to read the bmp file, get the red values from arrays and print it out in ASCII text. Thanks

EDIT: This isn't exactly steganograhpy. It is different as the code is hidden only in the first line and I need to use int[] arrays to array all pixels, then array the top line of pixels, then print out the red values in ASCII text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the classes `Picture` and `Pixel` since they're not in the standard library, but if [this](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~mehmud/cs401/lab6/Pixel.java) is the `Pixel` class you are using, try the following:

- create a method `decodeMessage(Picture image)` and get a `Pixel` array with `image.getPixels()` just like you did in `encodeMessage()`.
- loop through the message bits (using the `255` you put at the end of the encoding as an indicator for the sequence ending) and read the values with `pixelTarget.getRed()`. These values correspond to the encoded binary values. Generate an array for these bits.
- Now you have to convert every block of 7 bits into an integer. Use bitwise operations like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419501/converting-bits-in-to-integer) and cast the resulting `int` values to `char` values (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328996/java-change-int-to-ascii)).*
- Convert the `char` array to a `String` by passing the array to the `String` constructor.
- Print the string.

(*) Keep in mind that binary representations are ambiguous, so you have to decide what *byte order* you are using for the ASCII bits.