# what does << mean?

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I looked at the method which convert `ByteArray` to `int` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java) topic, and I feel a little bit confused when I look at this line:

`ret[2] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);`
if `>>` operator means this same as `>` operator when we working with int/float..?  When they are not equal, what is the meaning of it?

Comment: Search for `java operators`.

Comment: That means , not a good question and read [java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) docs.

Comment: yeah i get it http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm i don't know if i should delete this topic

Comment: these are bit wise operator. read java operators.

Comment: +1.  Just because something can be found in a Javadoc does not mean it shouldn't exist as a question on Stack Overflow.  @SotiriosDelimanolis "Search for java operators"... maybe somebody will do that and find this question.  It's useful.

Comment: @TJamesBoone You will notice, if you hover over the downvote arrow, `this question does not show any research effort`. OP could have take their title and put it in SO's search field with `java` and found the answer. This is also a duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Good point about duplicate.  It's unfortunate, because Pignic's answer is better than the answers on the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
8 >> 2 = 2
8 >> 3 = 1
```

in binary

```
00001000 >> 2 = 00000010
00001000 >> 3 = 00000001
```

And

```
1 << 2 = 4
1 << 3 = 8
```

in binary :

```
00000001 << 2 = 00000100
00000001 << 3 = 00001000
```

use ~ to negate :

```
byte b = ~01001000
```

then 
b is 10110111

The & operator is a bit intersection

```
10010101 & 01010011 = 00010001
```

And many others operator exist, and this is a very powerful way to do many things

Answer (score -1):

The right shift `>>` operator shifts the left operand to the right side with sign extension by the number of bits specified by its right operand. This means that a value at n place gets shifted to the right causing the n high order bits that contains the same value as that of unshifted value. This operator never throws an exception.

While `>` operator is simply used for comparison