# How to convert byte[4] to int (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a structure where there are 4 bytes that points out where should I read next.
The bytes seems to be: `50, -121, 5, 0` (just a sample)

I've been searching about how to convertt `byte[] to int` but not found any solution.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 4):

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
```