# Java - Convert byte[] to int[] rgb

Tags: java, arrays, converters

I have an int array that i obtained by using RobotPeer.getRGBPixels(). I convert it to an byte array to send it over socket by using:

```
 public static byte[] toByteArray(int[] ints){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ints.length * 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        bytes[i * 4] = (byte) (ints[i] & 0xFF);
        bytes[i * 4 + 1] = (byte) ((ints[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        bytes[i * 4 + 2] = (byte) ((ints[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
        bytes[i * 4 + 3] = (byte) ((ints[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

**Problem is:**
I use this method:

```
public static int[] toIntArray(byte buf[]) {
    int intArr[] = new int[buf.length / 4];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
        intArr[i] = (buf[3 + offset] & 0xFF) | ((buf[2 + offset] & 0xFF) << 8)
                | ((buf[1 + offset] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((buf[0 + offset] & 0xFF) << 24);
        offset += 4;
    }
    return intArr;
}
```

to get back int array. Then i create BufferedImage from it and i get:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p754u3tnivigu70/test.jpeg

Please help me to solve that problem.

Comment: You have the wrong byte order. Possible duplicate of [Byte Array and Int conversion in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java)

Comment: Use `ByteBuffer`s; they will manage bit handling for you and you can specify the endianness to use

Comment: @BrianRoach thank you, i sovled it. Sorry for create duplicate question, next time i will try to find out.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with bit shifting etc; Java has [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which can handle that for you, and endianness to boot:

```
public static int[] toIntArray(byte buf[]) 
{
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    final int[] ret = new int[buf.length / 4];
    buffer.asIntBuffer().put(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Similarly, the reverse:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(int[] ints)
{
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(ints.length * 4)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buf.asIntBuffer().put(ints);
    return buf.array();
}
```

Don't forget to specify endianness in your case since `ByteBuffer`s are big endian by default.

Comment: Thank for support but your toIntArray method throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.