# Java- Data parse on Android device BLE

Tags: java, android, parsing, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need help with Data parsing. I have device which send to my Android phone measured data in 7 byte format
x801FFF191FFF19

first byte is head (0x80)

next 3 bytes is 24 bit data1

and the last 3 bytes is 24 bit data2

Because I am a newbie in Java programming, I want to modify Android app from github [zh2x/SpO2-BLE-for-Android](https://github.com/zh2x/SpO2-BLE-for-Android). Gatt service and gatt characteristics already works.

I have problem with reading data. There is reading byte after byte and converting to integer. And I want to get data1 bytes to one integer value and data2 bytes to another one integer value.

[This is link for DataParse java file](https://github.com/zh2x/SpO2-BLE-for-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/berry_med/OximeterData/DataParser.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at

```
byte[] data1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(serviceData, 2, 5);
```

together with [Byte Array and Int conversion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399798/byte-array-and-int-conversion-in-java)